# What does the function StartJava do?

Tags: java

In Mathematica's autocomplete list, the function StartJava appeared. [image]

I searched the mathematica's reference site and found that the function was undocumented. What does it do?

Comment: What happens when you run ``??JLink`StartJava``?

Comment: Ahh it says `StartJava is deprecated. Use InstallJava instead.` @J.M.

Comment: So, can you answer your own question, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @J.M., it was discovered the `StartJava` was a deprecated function, replaced by `InstallJava`, which is used to launch the java runtime in Mathematica.

Comment: Now, you should wait at least several hours before you accept this answer to give others the chance. (Yes, sarcasm.) :)

Comment: @rcollyer not really: [Wait 48 hours. You must wait 2 days from the time you originally asked your question ...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)

Comment: @Kuba for some reason I had forgotten about that rule. :P

Comment: @rcollyer 2 years since your last question, I'm not surprised ;)

Comment: @Kuba hey, I've been busy. new kids, software that doesn't test itself, etc. :D